# How to export only NLA animations to GLB

Tags: animation, export, gltf, nla-editor

I have a model with dozen animations, but only a few of them are "pushed down" to NLA tracks. How to export only NLA animations to GLB? I somehow managed to do it before, but not now :)

For example: there is a "Roll" animation (1st screenshot), and there is not a NLA track with this animation. But GLB file has the "Roll" animation.

[image: many animations]
[image: some animations in NLA tracks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior changed between Blender 3.1 and Blender 3.2

In 3.1, only actions that are on NLA was exported.
Lots of people asked a way to export all actions, whatever they are on NLA or not.

So, in 3.2, when a single armature is exported, all armature action are exported.

During the development, I asked myself (and other community members) if I need to have this under an option. I didn't any feedback. At end, this new behavior was published without the option to deactivate it.

Seems this is what you are looking for.

So, I just added this option, that will be included in Blender 3.3

You will be able to export only actions that are on NLA by disabled this option :

[image]

Note: At time of writing my answer, this code is not yet merged in Blender 3.3 alpha

Edit: This is now part of 3.3 alpha